# Custom made HTML tags

Tags: html

Just came across a project that had custom-made tags. 
Something like:

```
<buildings>
    <building-1></building-1>
        <building-2></building-2>
</buildings>
```

(This code doesn't do anything; it's an example)
(It's not mine) (https://codepen.io/perbyhring/pen/jpQwav) What is the use of this?

Comment: There are multiple purposes for creating custom HTML tags. Have you read something like the [introduction to Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)?

Comment: You can create custom tags and create your own functionality for them.

Answer (score 1):

Those custom HTML elements have been introduced some time ago and should make HTML code more readable.

"Those elements provide a way to build own DOM elements but also have some drawbacks as simply defining and using an element called blue-button does not mean that the elements represent a button. Tools such as Web browsers, search engines, or accessibility technology will not automatically treat the resulting element as a button just based on its defined name."

Read more about them in the [html standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements).